# C# and XML selector

Tags: c#, xml, soap

Unfortunately, I don't know anything about C#, and I am just try to translate a piece of code seen below.

```
var body = Document.SelectSingleNode("//soap:Body/*[1]", Manager);
```

**Which element here is selected?** *Is it `<ds:KeyInfo>`?*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <xenc:EncryptedData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Id="ED-1B758D26C51BFCD86614340101135852" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content">
            <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"/>
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd" wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#EncryptedKey">
                    <wsse:Reference URI="#EK-1B758D26C51BFCD86614340101135741"/>
                </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
            <xenc:CipherData>
                <xenc:CipherValue></xenc:CipherValue>
            </xenc:CipherData>
        </xenc:EncryptedData>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: As said.. I'm not a C# developer.. I can't

Comment: This has nothing to do with C#. It is simply XPath and selecting <soap:Body>'s first child node (<xenc: ...)

Comment: @clarkk Tried to explain it to you in my answer. As Cetin Basoz mentioned, this has indeed nothing to do with C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at the [XPath Syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp), that should help you quite a bit.

Let me explain what element you are taking right now by using this expression: `//soap:Body/*[1]`. The `//` expression means you will take the node which matches the selection, in this case `soap:Body` no matter where it is. The `/` expression tells you to take a child from that node. The `*` wildcard matches any element node and the `[1]` tells it to take the first child.

Following all that, the current node you got is `xenc:EncryptedData`.